# Does Luden's Echo stack with Veigar?

Tags: league-of-legends

Would the passive on Luden's Echo stack with Veigar's Q?  According to the wiki:

> PASSIVE: Veigar permanently gains ability power every time he scores a takedown against an enemy champion.
>
> ABILITY POWER GAINED: +1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 AP
>
> Whenever Veigar kills a unit with Baleful Strike, he gains +1 AP, doubled to +2 AP against champions and large monsters and minions.
>
> ACTIVE: Veigar unleashes a bolt of dark energy, dealing magic damage to the first two units hit.

So if you threw Veigar's Q into a group of low minions, and the three bolts from Luden's Echo's passive kill three extra minions (totaling 5 minions killed), would you gain bonus AP from those 3 minions also besides the two you hit with the spell?  Why or Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you don't get the stacks from Luden's kill. It's fair since the describtion says  that the *Baleful Strike* must kill the unit and not the *Luden*'s passive.

Why is that so? Hard to say, there was once the determination (maybe I am able to find the official statement and can add it later), that permanent stacking in general doesn't cumulate with any items' effects. Reason is balancing probably. Furthermore this question arised when *Iceborn Gauntlet* was introduced and when it came to the conflict with *Nasus*' Q.

Another example is Gangplank; he used to get bonus gold when he killed minions with the Tiamat/Hydra passive, but this has similarly been removed.